# How to apply filter on map and lambda expression in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am using below query to fetch the location id and location name from data set.

```
location = list(map(lambda x: {'locationid': x['id'], 'locationname': x['name']}, data ))
```

location contains some null values also. I want to filter null values before assigning to location.

example :

```
name = list(map(lambda x: {
            'empName': x}, set(x['empName'] for x in response if x['empName'] != None)))
```

Comment: There is a function called `filter`, why don't you use it?

Comment: And what is the problem with the second code? It appears like it might already do what you want.

Comment: second code having only one variable. We want to apply filter for two variable now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`list-map-lambda` is overcomplication for your case, use a simple list comprehension:

```
locations = [{'locationid': x['id'], 'locationname': x['name']} for x in data if x]
```